# Как расположить QTabBar по центру? Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, qtabwidget, qtabbar

[image: Картинка]

Как можно вкладки расположить по центру?

Пробовал данный вариант:

```
QTabBar::tab {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Но он делает отступ от каждой вкладки, что мне не надо:

[image: Картинка]

Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: dujor21, почему вы никак не реагируете на ответы, которые вам предоставляются на ваши вопросы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сделает каждую вкладку одинаковой ширины, а также расширяемой,
надо переопределить метод [**tabSizeHint()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#tabSizeHint) класса [**QTabBar**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
class TabBar(QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        size = QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        w = int(self.width()/self.count())
        return QSize(w, size.height())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(596, 332)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        self.tabWidget.setTabBar(TabBar())                                
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(True)
        self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
        self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
        
        
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Страница"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabWidget.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE**:

> Я не хочу растягивать вкладки, я просто хочу расположить их по центру.

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        tab = QTabWidget()
        tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'Tab 1')
        tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'Tab 1')
        tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'Страница')
        
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(tab)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QTabWidget::tab-bar {
                alignment: center;
            }
        ''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @dujor21 что не так?

Comment: Немного не то, что хотел

Comment: @dujor21 пожалуйста, объясните лучше, что значит не то что вы хотели? И учтите, что средствами qss вы это не сделаете.

Comment: Я не хочу растягивать вкладки, я просто хочу расположить их по центру.

Comment: @dujor21 я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.